how to use java files in Android Flavors
I have the same java class in two different Android Flavors.
When using the class, the compiler complains that he doesn't know that class.
When I switch the java class to kotlin, everything compiles.
Do java classes in Flavors not work?
Any idea how to solve this?
I'm using Android Studio Jellyfish (version 2023.3.1)
How to reproduce:
In the main source code use something like
Log.e("1", MyTest.getText() );

in the gradle file, define a flavor like
flavorDimensions = ["MyFlavor"]
productFlavors {
    Flavor1
    {
        dimension "MyFlavor"
    }
    ....
}

in directory app\src\MyFlavor\java\com\example\myapplication define the class MyTest.java
class MyTest
{
    static String getText()
    {
        return "abc";
    }
}

when compiling one gets:
....app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\MainActivity.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        Log.e("1", MyTest.getText() );
                   ^
  symbol:   variable MyTest
  location: class MainActivity

convert MyTest to Kotlin and everything compiles.
